# Use document .hml format instead of .pdf

Tags: c#, html, docusignapi

Context:
I'm using DocuSign.eSign nuget package in a webapi to send PDF files for signing to customers, this is working as expected (I'm in at the inception phase for the bigger picture).

Problem:
I've been reading [here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-supported-file-formats) that .html document can be sent for signing. I'm looking forward to find some documents or snippet examples of how I should send an envelope with .html document for signing.

Motivation:
It will be a really nice way to deal (saving weeks of coding) with plain html rather than using PDF generation for fancy documents designs and having variant widths and heights or not having fixed places position where the signature or other inputs needs to land.

Question:
Is it possible to do this where I can find more details? If is possible how I will need to define signer tabs? width x height as for pdf's or html tags + attributes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's several ways to place tabs (fields) with DocuSign, see the response I just posted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general there are three methods of placing DocuSign tabs:

1. Absolute (or Fixed) positioning.
2. Relative (aka Anchor or AutoPlace) positioning.
3. PDF Form Fields

#### Absolute Positioning

This is most useful when you have fixed documents or docs that don't change often and you have the luxury of trial and error to find the location(s) that work well then save those locations for future use.  The coordinate system works with the origin (0,0) being the top left of the page, and you specify the page number and x,y in terms of pixels for where you want the tabs.  For instance, to place one signature tab 100 pixels right and 200 pixels down from the top left of page 1 of the first document:

```
{
    "signHereTabs": [
        {
            "xPosition": "100",
            "yPosition": "200",
            "documentId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Relative (aka Anchor Tagging or AutoPlace) Positioning

With Anchor Tagging you can tell the system to place signature tabs (or any other DocuSign tab) on your documents based on document content itself.  For instance, if you have the text in your document

"Please Sign Here"

Then you can have the system place a signature tab at that location, or even better, at that location but with an offset in terms of inches, pixels, mms, etc.  For instance, if you want to place a signature tab 1-inch to the right and .5 inches down from the text "Please Sign Here"

```
{  
    "signHereTabs":[  
        {  
            "anchorString":"Please Sign Here",
            "anchorXOffset":"1",
            "anchorYOffset":".5",
            "anchorUnits":"inches",
            "recipientId":"1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that you do not specify `pageNumber` for anchor'ed tabs, which means that the system will place tabs WHEREVER it finds the `anchorString` value in your documents.

#### PDF Form Fields Positioning

You can also supply (non-flattened) PDF files with form fields in them and have the DocuSign platform convert the PDF fields into DocuSign fields, at the same locations.  Furthermore you can tell the system to convert into specific tab types based on the field names.  For more info see the *Transform PDF Fields* section on this API guide [page](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Document%20Parameters.htm).

All this info can be found through the [DocuSign Developer Center](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center).

Comment: Hi Ergin, thank you for detailed answer, I managed to send html to docusign, now I have another problem, how I will set up images in HTML, because none of the images are shown in generated pdf? what are the supported html doc-types html 4, html 5?